# How to input for arrays I don't know the length of?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I'm trying to make a program that accepts the number of students enrolled to an exam, and how many points each of them got. I try to loop the inputs but it gives seemingly random numbers in output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int studenti;
    scanf("%d", &studenti);
    printf("%d ", studenti);
    int niza[studenti];
    for (int i = 1; i <= studenti; i++){
        scanf("%d", &niza[i]);
        i++;
        printf("%d ",niza[i]);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to add array elements without knowing how big the array will be beforehand because I don't know how big they are when I pass the checks on my uni website.

Comment: Can you show us the input you give and the output as well?

Comment: Also, why are you incrementing `i` twice?

Comment: When the size of an array is `studenti`, then valid indexes for the array are `0` to `studenti - 1`. However, you are using the indexes `1` to `studenti`, so you are accessing the array out of bounds. Therefore, you must make the change mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that the `for` loop begins with `1` and continues to `i <= studenti`. In C, arrays begin with index '0' and the final index in this example is `studenti - 1`.
Another issue is the `for` loop increments `i` and there is an `i++;` in the body of the loop. `i` is incremented twice.
Check the return from `scanf`. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. Here that would be 1, 0 or EOF.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int studenti = 0; // initialize
    if ( 1 == scanf("%d", &studenti)) { // successful scan
        printf("%d ", studenti);
        int niza[studenti]; // variable length array
        for (int i = 0; i < studenti; i++) { // start from index 0
            if ( 1 == scanf("%d", &niza[i])) {
                printf("%d ",niza[i]);
            }
            else { // scanf returned 0 or EOF
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem scanning array element\n");
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else { // scanf returned 0 or EOF
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem scanning\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the length, you should probably create a linked list instead of a static array, and `malloc` another list element for each student.